# Arrays in C - Last element assigned value of index

Tags: c, arrays

Basically I'm having a really weird issue where with any array I create, the last element is assigned its index as a value, and this value is immutable (any assignment statement doesn't change the value). So for example if I declare/initialise an array of integers as

```
int arr[5] = {0};
```

then print the values, I get `0,0,0,0,0,5`. Even an explicit assignment to the last element (e.g. "`arr[5] = 0;`") does nothing, it retains the value 5.

Comment: Please post your code.

Answer (score 3):

`arr[5]` is out of scope of your array. If you declare an array with size, you can have access from `0 to size-1` index. As you defined `int arr[5]`, you have access `a[0]` to `a[4]`.

Comment: Ohhhh, that makes sense! I'm still new to C, so to me arr[5] means I have an array with 6 elements (0-5) :P

Answer (score 0):

You declare `arr` to have 5 items, but you print six items. The last one is actually NOT an array item, you print some undefined data.